# Angular Testing Uncaught Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'params')

Tags: angular, routes, karma-jasmine, angular-test

I have problem with testing my component. The main problem is when I run fixture.detectChanges().
When I do not fire it, all tests pass without any problems.
This is the tests:

```js
  describe("simple HTML", () => {
    // beforeEach(() => {
    //   fixture.detectChanges();
    // });
    it('should be created', () => {
      expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  
    });

    it("Component should render html h3 tag with title Icons & Measuerements", () => {
      const h3Ele = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css(".mainTitle"));
      expect(h3Ele.nativeElement.textContent).toBe("Icons & Measurements")
    })
    it("Should render h3 tag with text 'Files from blower:' and span with information about current container", () => {
      const h3Ele = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css(".headerh3"))
      expect(h3Ele.nativeElement.innerHTML).toBe("Files from blower: <span _ngcontent-a-c391=\"\"></span>")
    })
    it("Should display current blower that user is at the moment in span", async () => {
      const h3Ele = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css(".headerh3 span"))
      // component.lowBlowId = "test_id"
      // fixture.detectChanges()
      debugger
      
    
    })
  })
```

But then i fire this detectChanges() i have this error:
[image]

I think the issue may be params in one function i created in ts file.

```js
  async gettingLowBlowId() {
    this.route.parent.params.subscribe((params) => {
      this.lowBlowId = params.blower_id
    })
  }
```

This is my set up in tests:

```js
 let component: IconsInVisualizationComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<IconsInVisualizationComponent>;
  let administrationServiceMock: AdnimistrationSiteService;
  let visualisationFileStorageManagerServiceMock: VisualisationFileStorageManagerService

  beforeEach(async () => {
    administrationServiceMock = jasmine.createSpyObj("AdnimistrationSiteService", ["getAllFilesWithIcons", "changeOrDeleteIcon", "getSensorsForMapping", "deleteSensorsAttachToIcon"])
    visualisationFileStorageManagerServiceMock = jasmine.createSpyObj("VisualisationFileStorageManagerService", ["getFoldersList"])

     await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpClientModule,
        MatDialogModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule, 
        RouterTestingModule,
        MatSnackBarModule,
        MatTableModule,
      ],
      providers: [
        {provide: AdnimistrationSiteService, useValue: administrationServiceMock},
        {provide: VisualisationFileStorageManagerService, useValue: visualisationFileStorageManagerServiceMock},
      ],
      declarations: [ IconsInVisualizationComponent ],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(IconsInVisualizationComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });
```

Can you help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In your providers you probably need to add the `ActivatedRoute` like this :

```js
providers: [
  ...,
  {
    provide: ActivatedRoute,
    useValue: {
      parent: {
        params: of({ blower_id: 2 })
      }
    }
  }
],
```

Comment: I added answer to this comment as a answer to my question, because i dont wanted to add code snippet