# Angular Testing: Uncaught Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subscribe')

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine, angular-test

Follow up on the previous post stack: [StackLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69645202/angular-testing-uncaught-error-uncaught-in-promise-typeerror-cannot-read-pr/69645717?noredirect=1#comment123103104_69645717)
Okay so i add this ActivatedRoute to my code:

```js
await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpClientModule,
        MatDialogModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule, 
        RouterTestingModule,
        MatSnackBarModule,
        MatTableModule,
      ],
      providers: [
        {provide: AdnimistrationSiteService, useValue: administrationServiceMock},
        {provide: VisualisationFileStorageManagerService, useValue: visualisationFileStorageManagerServiceMock},
        {
          provide: ActivatedRoute,
          useValue: {
            parent: {
              params: of({ blower_id: "test_id" })
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      declarations: [ IconsInVisualizationComponent ],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });
```

But i run on the different issue this time:

[image]

This is the code that causes the issue probably by this two functions. Is there chance is caused by toUpperCase() in the parameter or there is different issue?

```js
async getDataForIconsAndSensors() {
    this.gettingLowBlowId()
    this.getSensorsToDisplay()
    this.gettingConatiners()
    this.adnimistrationSiteService.getAllFilesWithIcons(this.lowBlowId.toUpperCase())
    .subscribe(async data => {
      this.loadedData = data;
      await this.changeIconResponse(this.loadedData);
      this.dataSource.data = this.loadedData;
    })
  }


  // this method allow to change or delete icon from the blower

   changeIcons(elementFileName: string, valueToUpdate: string, blowerId: string) {
    this.adnimistrationSiteService.changeOrDeleteIcon(elementFileName, valueToUpdate, blowerId).subscribe()
    this.getDataForIconsAndSensors()
  }
```

Comment: I think you should mock this service method

Comment: @RebaiAhmed Is right. Please provide `visualisationFileStorageManagerServiceMock` and `administrationServiceMock`

Comment: You can use https://github.com/ike18t/ts-mockery to mock services